# gettext - Load local catalogs

Tags: c++, c, localization, gettext

While developing and translating an application, it might be nice if `gettext` will use the catalogs found in the local `po/` dir so it wouldn't be necessary to call `make install` each time.

Is there a way to do it?

One of the problems is the naming convention: `gettext` looks for the catalog files in an hierarchy that looks like `/usr/share/locale/LL/LC_MESSAGES/package.mo` (where LL is two-letter language code), while usually in the development tree the binary catalogs reside in `po/LL.gmo`.

Answer (score 0):

*it might be nice if gettext will use the catalogs found in the local po/ dir so it wouldn't be necessary to call make install each time....Is there a way to do it?*

If I am understanding your idea correctly, it sounds like ***[gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)*** ***is able to do just that*** (i.e. change the translation path variable) if you follow the prescribed methods to set it up...

> Translations should be stored in a path having a fixed structure.
>   First of all, we’ll have a root folder named to your taste (for
>   example “languages”). Inside it, we have to create a folder for every
>   targeted language whose name must comply to the ISO 3166 standard. So,
>   valid names for an Italian translation can be “it_IT” (Italian of
>   Italy), “it_CH” (Italian of Switzerland), “en_US” (English of USA),
>   and so on. Within the folder having the language code, we must have a
>   folder named “LC_MESSAGES” where, finally, we’ll store the translation
>   files.

***[From Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/managing-gettext-translations-shared-hosting/)***  (there is a script example included in this link showing one method to perform this task)

***Change*** *"languages"* in description above to *"po"*, and that may do what you want?

Comment: I think mimicking the hierarchy of the binary catalogs in the development sources will not be compatible with the automake macros that come with gettext and compile the `*.po` files into `*.mo` files.